# How should I convert a PublicKey to a Certificate in Java

Tags: java, security, keystore, public-key

I have a circumstance where I need to store one or more public keys for use in authentication. I would like to store them in a KeyStore as TrustedCertificates - is there a way to do this, ideally using standard java.security classes?

I have seen that I can generate certificates with Bouncycastle, but most examples seem to show examples of chains of trust, whereas in my case I have individual trusted keys. Also, all the examples I have seen deal with key-pairs, but I am only interested in the set of public keys provided. Is it possible to create a certificate containing only a public key?

Comment: Okay, the question is, do you want a `Certificate` like an X509Certificate, or do you want to use this as a client authentication mechanism using a PKCS12 file? If you have a PKCS12 file, then you need the corresponding private key to create a PKCS12 file out of the private key and the X509Certificate. I'm not sure what you mean by "individual trusted keys", the whole point of a chain of trust is that the CA signs the X509Certificate, and if the CA is trusted, then so are all the certificates. For this, there is a CA which provides the X509Certificate by signing the PKCS10 CSR.

Comment: I personally had to mess around with this a week ago or two, but I don't have enough data about your architecture to properly answer the question.

Comment: Technically, a public key isn't really worth anything for the sake of SSL client-certificate authentication, because it needs a private key too. But if that's not what you need it for, then we might get somewhere.

Comment: This might be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26782357/2413303

Comment: I am using the keys to verify signed JWTs (verifying cryptographic signatures to establish trust in claims). As such I only need a set of public keys.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you cannot create certificate without private key.

Long answer: [google "java create self signed certificate programmatically"](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+create+self+signed+certificate+programmatically), e.g.: https://www.mayrhofer.eu.org/post/create-x509-certs-in-java/