# Simple JWT authentication in ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm looking for the simplest way to setup a Web API server that uses JWTs for authentication in ASP.NET Core (aka ASP.NET 5). This project ([blog post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/369657/Simple-Authentication-using-Jwt-in-Asp-Net-Web-Api?msg=5199064#xx5199064xx) / [github](https://github.com/stewartm83/Jwt-WebApi)) does exactly what I'm looking for but it uses ASP.NET 4.

I just want to be able to:

1. setup a login route that can create a JWT token and return it in the header. I'm integrating this with an existing RESTful service that will tell me if the username and password are valid. In the ASP.NET 4 project I'm looking at this could be done with the following route https://github.com/stewartm83/Jwt-WebApi/blob/master/src/JwtWebApi/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L24-L54
2. Intercept incoming requests to routes that require authorization, decrypt and validate the JWT token coming in the header and make the user information in the JWT token's payload accessible to the route. e.g. something like this: https://github.com/stewartm83/Jwt-WebApi/blob/master/src/JwtWebApi/App_Start/AuthHandler.cs

All of the examples I've seen in ASP.NET Core are very complex and rely on some or all of OAuth, IS, OpenIddict, and EF which I would like to avoid.

Can anyone point me towards an example of how to do this in ASP.NET Core or help me get started with this?

**EDIT: Answer**
I ended up using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33217340/373655

Comment: Here a step by step tutorial Implement JWT in .NET 5 https://codepedia.info/jwt-authentication-in-aspnet-core-web-api-token

Answer (score 53):

**Note/Update:**

The below code was for .NET Core 1.1 
Since .NET Core 1 was so very RTM, authentication changed with the jump from .NET Core 1 to 2.0 (aka was [partially?] fixed with breaking changes). 
That's why the bellow code does NOT work with .NET Core 2.0 anymore.
But it will still be a useful read.

#### 2018 Update

Meanwhile, you can find a working example of ASP.NET Core 2.0 JWT-Cookie-Authentication [on my github test repo](https://github.com/ststeiger/AuthTest).
Comes complete with an implementation of the MS-RSA&MS-ECDSA abstract class with BouncyCastle, and a key-generator for RSA&ECDSA.

---

Necromancing.
I digged deeper into JWT. Here are my findings:

You need to add Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer

then you can set

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(bearerOptions);
```

in Startup.cs => Configure

where bearerOptions is defined by you, e.g. as

```
var bearerOptions = new JwtBearerOptions()
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters,
    Events = new CustomBearerEvents()
};

// Optional 
// bearerOptions.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
// bearerOptions.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new MyTokenHandler());
```

where CustomBearerEvents is the place where you could add token data to the httpContext/Route

```
// https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/Events/JwtBearerEvents.cs
public class CustomBearerEvents : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.IJwtBearerEvents
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked if exceptions are thrown during request processing. The exceptions will be re-thrown after this event unless suppressed.
    /// </summary>
    public Func<AuthenticationFailedContext, Task> OnAuthenticationFailed { get; set; } = context => Task.FromResult(0);

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when a protocol message is first received.
    /// </summary>
    public Func<MessageReceivedContext, Task> OnMessageReceived { get; set; } = context => Task.FromResult(0);

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked after the security token has passed validation and a ClaimsIdentity has been generated.
    /// </summary>
    public Func<TokenValidatedContext, Task> OnTokenValidated { get; set; } = context => Task.FromResult(0);


    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked before a challenge is sent back to the caller.
    /// </summary>
    public Func<JwtBearerChallengeContext, Task> OnChallenge { get; set; } = context => Task.FromResult(0);


    Task IJwtBearerEvents.AuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedContext context)
    {
        return OnAuthenticationFailed(context);
    }

    Task IJwtBearerEvents.Challenge(JwtBearerChallengeContext context)
    {
        return OnChallenge(context);
    }

    Task IJwtBearerEvents.MessageReceived(MessageReceivedContext context)
    {
        return OnMessageReceived(context);
    }

    Task IJwtBearerEvents.TokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext context)
    {
        return OnTokenValidated(context);
    }
}
```

And tokenValidationParameters is defined by you, e.g.

```
var tokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
{
    // The signing key must match!
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,

    // Validate the JWT Issuer (iss) claim
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidIssuer = "ExampleIssuer",

    // Validate the JWT Audience (aud) claim
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidAudience = "ExampleAudience",

    // Validate the token expiry
    ValidateLifetime = true,

    // If you want to allow a certain amount of clock drift, set that here:
    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero, 
};
```

And MyTokenHandler is optionally defined by you, if you want to customize token validation, e.g.

```
// https://gist.github.com/pmhsfelix/4151369
public class MyTokenHandler : Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ISecurityTokenValidator
{
    private int m_MaximumTokenByteSize;

    public MyTokenHandler()
    { }

    bool ISecurityTokenValidator.CanValidateToken
    {
        get
        {
            // throw new NotImplementedException();
            return true;
        }
    }



    int ISecurityTokenValidator.MaximumTokenSizeInBytes
    {
        get
        {
            return this.m_MaximumTokenByteSize;
        }

        set
        {
            this.m_MaximumTokenByteSize = value;
        }
    }

    bool ISecurityTokenValidator.CanReadToken(string securityToken)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(securityToken);
        return true;
    }

    ClaimsPrincipal ISecurityTokenValidator.ValidateToken(string securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        // validatedToken = new JwtSecurityToken(securityToken);
        try
        {

            tokenHandler.ValidateToken(securityToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
            validatedToken = new JwtSecurityToken("jwtEncodedString");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }



        ClaimsPrincipal principal = null;
        // SecurityToken validToken = null;

        validatedToken = null;


        System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Security.Claims.Claim> ls =
            new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Security.Claims.Claim>();

        ls.Add(
            new System.Security.Claims.Claim(
                System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name, "IcanHazUsr_éèêëïàáâäåãæóòôöõõúùûüñçø_ÉÈÊËÏÀÁÂÄÅÃÆÓÒÔÖÕÕÚÙÛÜÑÇØ 你好，世界 Привет\tмир"
            , System.Security.Claims.ClaimValueTypes.String
            )
        );

        // 

        System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity id = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity("authenticationType");
        id.AddClaims(ls);

        principal = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal(id);

        return principal;
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


}
```

The tricky part is how to get the AsymmetricSecurityKey, because you don't want to pass a rsaCryptoServiceProvider, because you need interoperability in crypto format.

Creation goes along the lines of

```
// System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 cert2 = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(byte[] rawData);
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 cert2 = 
    DotNetUtilities.CreateX509Cert2("mycert");
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityKey secKey = new X509SecurityKey(cert2);
```

e.g. with BouncyCastle from a DER Certificate:

```
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942094/how-can-i-generate-a-self-signed-cert-without-using-obsolete-bouncycastle-1-7-0
    public static System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 CreateX509Cert2(string certName)
    {

        var keypairgen = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Generators.RsaKeyPairGenerator();
        keypairgen.Init(new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.KeyGenerationParameters(
            new Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SecureRandom(
                new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Prng.CryptoApiRandomGenerator()
                )
                , 1024
                )
        );

        Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keypair = keypairgen.GenerateKeyPair();

        // --- Until here we generate a keypair



        var random = new Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SecureRandom(
                new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Prng.CryptoApiRandomGenerator()
        );


        // SHA1WITHRSA
        // SHA256WITHRSA
        // SHA384WITHRSA
        // SHA512WITHRSA

        // SHA1WITHECDSA
        // SHA224WITHECDSA
        // SHA256WITHECDSA
        // SHA384WITHECDSA
        // SHA512WITHECDSA

        Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = 
            new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Operators.Asn1SignatureFactory("SHA512WITHRSA", keypair.Private, random)
        ;



        var gen = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509V3CertificateGenerator();


        var CN = new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509.X509Name("CN=" + certName);
        var SN = Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger.ProbablePrime(120, new Random());

        gen.SetSerialNumber(SN);
        gen.SetSubjectDN(CN);
        gen.SetIssuerDN(CN);
        gen.SetNotAfter(DateTime.Now.AddYears(1));
        gen.SetNotBefore(DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)));
        gen.SetPublicKey(keypair.Public);


        // -- Are these necessary ? 

        // public static readonly DerObjectIdentifier AuthorityKeyIdentifier = new DerObjectIdentifier("2.5.29.35");
        // OID value: 2.5.29.35
        // OID description: id-ce-authorityKeyIdentifier
        // This extension may be used either as a certificate or CRL extension. 
        // It identifies the public key to be used to verify the signature on this certificate or CRL.
        // It enables distinct keys used by the same CA to be distinguished (e.g., as key updating occurs).

        
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930381/generating-x509-certificate-using-bouncy-castle-java
        gen.AddExtension(
        Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509.X509Extensions.AuthorityKeyIdentifier.Id,
        false,
        new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509.AuthorityKeyIdentifier(
            Org.BouncyCastle.X509.SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(keypair.Public),
            new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509.GeneralNames(new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509.GeneralName(CN)),
            SN
        ));

        // OID value: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1
        // OID description: Indicates that a certificate can be used as an SSL server certificate.
        gen.AddExtension(
            Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509.X509Extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage.Id,
            false,
            new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509.ExtendedKeyUsage(new ArrayList()
            {
            new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1")
        }));

        // -- End are these necessary ? 

        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate bouncyCert = gen.Generate(signatureFactory);

        byte[] ba = bouncyCert.GetEncoded();
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 msCert = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(ba);
        return msCert;
    }
```

Subsequently, you can add a custom cookie-format that contains the JWT-Bearer:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance",
    CookieName = "SecurityByObscurityDoesntWork",
    ExpireTimeSpan = new System.TimeSpan(15, 0, 0),
    LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Account/Unauthorized/"),
    AccessDeniedPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Account/Forbidden/"),
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    CookieSecure = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest,
    CookieHttpOnly = false,
    TicketDataFormat = new CustomJwtDataFormat("foo", tokenValidationParameters)

    // DataProtectionProvider = null,

    // DataProtectionProvider = new DataProtectionProvider(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"c:\shared-auth-ticket-keys\"),
    //delegate (DataProtectionConfiguration options)
    //{
    //    var op = new Microsoft.AspNet.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.AuthenticatedEncryptionOptions();
    //    op.EncryptionAlgorithm = Microsoft.AspNet.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.EncryptionAlgorithm.AES_256_GCM:
    //    options.UseCryptographicAlgorithms(op);
    //}
    //),
});
```

Where CustomJwtDataFormat  is something along the lines of

```
public class CustomJwtDataFormat : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
{

    private readonly string algorithm;
    private readonly TokenValidationParameters validationParameters;

    public CustomJwtDataFormat(string algorithm, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
    {
        this.algorithm = algorithm;
        this.validationParameters = validationParameters;
    }

    

    // This ISecureDataFormat implementation is decode-only
    string ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>.Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
    {
        return MyProtect(data, null);
    }

    string ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>.Protect(AuthenticationTicket data, string purpose)
    {
        return MyProtect(data, purpose);
    }

    AuthenticationTicket ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>.Unprotect(string protectedText)
    {
        return MyUnprotect(protectedText, null);
    }

    AuthenticationTicket ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>.Unprotect(string protectedText, string purpose)
    {
        return MyUnprotect(protectedText, purpose);
    }


    private string MyProtect(AuthenticationTicket data, string purpose)
    {
        return "wadehadedudada";
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }


    // http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/01/20/aggressive-inlining-in-the-clr-45-jit/
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImpl(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    private AuthenticationTicket MyUnprotect(string protectedText, string purpose)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        ClaimsPrincipal principal = null;
        SecurityToken validToken = null;


        System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Security.Claims.Claim> ls = 
            new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Security.Claims.Claim>();

        ls.Add(
            new System.Security.Claims.Claim(
                System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name, "IcanHazUsr_éèêëïàáâäåãæóòôöõõúùûüñçø_ÉÈÊËÏÀÁÂÄÅÃÆÓÒÔÖÕÕÚÙÛÜÑÇØ 你好，世界 Привет\tмир"
            , System.Security.Claims.ClaimValueTypes.String
            )
        );

        // 

        System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity id = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity("authenticationType");
        id.AddClaims(ls);

        principal = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal(id);
        return new AuthenticationTicket(principal, new AuthenticationProperties(), "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance");


        try
        {
            principal = handler.ValidateToken(protectedText, this.validationParameters, out validToken);

            JwtSecurityToken validJwt = validToken as JwtSecurityToken;

            if (validJwt == null)
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentException("Invalid JWT");
            }

            if (!validJwt.Header.Alg.Equals(algorithm, System.StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentException($"Algorithm must be '{algorithm}'");
            }

            // Additional custom validation of JWT claims here (if any)
        }
        catch (SecurityTokenValidationException)
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (System.ArgumentException)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // Validation passed. Return a valid AuthenticationTicket:
        return new AuthenticationTicket(principal, new AuthenticationProperties(), "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance");
    }


}
```

And you can also create the JWT-token with Microsoft.IdentityModel.Token:

```
// https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/Events/IJwtBearerEvents.cs
// http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45974/web-api-2-authentication-with-jwt
public class TokenMaker
{

    class SecurityConstants
    {
        public static string TokenIssuer;
        public static string TokenAudience;
        public static int TokenLifetimeMinutes;
    }


    public static string IssueToken()
    {
        SecurityKey sSKey = null;

        var claimList = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "userName"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "role")     //Not sure what this is for
        };

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        SecurityTokenDescriptor desc = makeSecurityTokenDescriptor(sSKey, claimList);

        // JwtSecurityToken tok = tokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(desc);
        return tokenHandler.CreateEncodedJwt(desc);
    }

    
    public static ClaimsPrincipal ValidateJwtToken(string jwtToken)
    {
        SecurityKey sSKey = null;
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        // Parse JWT from the Base64UrlEncoded wire form 
        //(<Base64UrlEncoded header>.<Base64UrlEncoded body>.<signature>)
        JwtSecurityToken parsedJwt = tokenHandler.ReadToken(jwtToken) as JwtSecurityToken;

        TokenValidationParameters validationParams =
            new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidAudience = SecurityConstants.TokenAudience,
                ValidIssuers = new List<string>() { SecurityConstants.TokenIssuer },
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = sSKey,
                
            };

        SecurityToken secT;
        return tokenHandler.ValidateToken("token", validationParams, out secT);
    }


    private static SecurityTokenDescriptor makeSecurityTokenDescriptor(SecurityKey sSKey, List<Claim> claimList)
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Claim[] claims = claimList.ToArray();
        return new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
            Issuer = SecurityConstants.TokenIssuer,
            Audience = SecurityConstants.TokenAudience,
            IssuedAt = System.DateTime.UtcNow,
            Expires = System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(SecurityConstants.TokenLifetimeMinutes),
            NotBefore = System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddTicks(-1),

            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(sSKey, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha512Signature)
        };

        

    }

}
```

Note that because you can give a different user in the cookie vs. http-headers (Bearer), or any other authentication method that you specify, you can actually have MORE than 1 user !

---

Take a look at this:
https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core

it should be exactly what you're looking for.

There's also these two:

https://goblincoding.com/2016/07/03/issuing-and-authenticating-jwt-tokens-in-asp-net-core-webapi-part-i/

https://goblincoding.com/2016/07/07/issuing-and-authenticating-jwt-tokens-in-asp-net-core-webapi-part-ii/

and this one
http://blog.novanet.no/hooking-up-asp-net-core-1-rc1-web-api-with-auth0-bearer-tokens/

And the JWT-Bearer sources
https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer

---

If you need ultra-high security, you should protect against replay-attacks by renewing the ticket on each request, and invalidate old tickets after a certain timeout, and after user logout (not just after validity expiration).

---

For those of you who end up from here via google, you can implement a TicketDataFormat in cookie-authentication when you want to use your own version of JWT.

I had to look into JWT for work, because we needed to secure our application. 
Because I still had to use .NET 2.0, I had to write my own library.

I've ported the result of that to .NET Core this weekend.
You find it here:
https://github.com/ststeiger/Jwt_Net20/tree/master/CoreJWT

It doesn't use any database, that's not the job of a JWT libary. 
Getting and setting DB data is your job. 
The library allows for JWT authorization and verification in .NET Core with all algorithms [specified in the JWT RFC listed on the IANA JOSE assignment](http://www.iana.org/assignments/jose/jose.xhtml). 
As for adding authorization to the pipeline and adding values to route - these are two things which should be done separately, and I think you best do that yourselfs.

You can use custom authentication in ASP.NET Core. 
Look into the ["Security" category of docs on docs.asp.net.](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/index.html)

Or you can look into the [Cookie Middleware without ASP.NET Identity](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html) or into [Custom Policy-Based Authorization](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html).

You can also learn more in the [auth workshop on github](https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetAuthorizationWorkshop) or in the [social login](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/sociallogins.html) section or in [this channel 9 video tutorial](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Seth-Juarez/ASPNET-Core-Authorization-with-Barry-Dorrans).
If all else fails, the source code of asp.net security is [on github](https://github.com/aspnet/Security%20which%20includes%20some%20samples).

---

The original project for .NET 3.5, which is where my library derives from, is here:
https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt
I removed all references to LINQ + extension methods, because they are not supported in .NET 2.0. If you include either LINQ, or ExtensionAttribute in the sourcecode, then you can't just change the .NET runtime without getting warnings; that's why I have completely removed them. 
Also, I've added RSA + ECDSA JWS-methods, for that reason the CoreJWT-project depends on BouncyCastle. 
If you limit yourselfs to HMAC-SHA256 + HMAC-SHA384 + HMAC-SHA512, you can remove BouncyCastle.

JWE is not (yet) supported.

Usage is just like jwt-dotnet/jwt, **except I changed the namespace JWT to CoreJWT**. 
I also added an internal copy of PetaJSON as serializer, so there is no interference with other people's project's dependencies.

Create a JWT-token:

```
var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { "claim1", 0 },
    { "claim2", "claim2-value" }
};
var secretKey = "GQDstcKsx0NHjPOuXOYg5MbeJ1XT0uFiwDVvVBrk";
string token = JWT.JsonWebToken.Encode(payload, secretKey, JWT.JwtHashAlgorithm.HS256);
Console.WriteLine(token);
```

Verify a JWT-token:

```
var token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjbGFpbTEiOjAsImNsYWltMiI6ImNsYWltMi12YWx1ZSJ9.8pwBI_HtXqI3UgQHQ_rDRnSQRxFL1SR8fbQoS-5kM5s";
var secretKey = "GQDstcKsx0NHjPOuXOYg5MbeJ1XT0uFiwDVvVBrk";
try
{
    string jsonPayload = JWT.JsonWebToken.Decode(token, secretKey);
    Console.WriteLine(jsonPayload);
}
catch (JWT.SignatureVerificationException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid token!");
}
```

For RSA & ECSA, you'll have to pass the (BouncyCastle) RSA/ECDSA private key instead of secretKey.

```
namespace BouncyJWT
{


    public class JwtKey
    {
        public byte[] MacKeyBytes;
        public Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricKeyParameter RsaPrivateKey;
        public Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.ECPrivateKeyParameters EcPrivateKey;


        public string MacKey
        {
            get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(this.MacKeyBytes); }
            set { this.MacKeyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value); }
        }


        public JwtKey()
        { }

        public JwtKey(string macKey)
        {
            this.MacKey = macKey;
        }

        public JwtKey(byte[] macKey)
        {
            this.MacKeyBytes = macKey;
        }

        public JwtKey(Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricKeyParameter rsaPrivateKey)
        {
            this.RsaPrivateKey = rsaPrivateKey;
        }

        public JwtKey(Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.ECPrivateKeyParameters ecPrivateKey)
        {
            this.EcPrivateKey = ecPrivateKey;
        }
    }


}
```

For how to generate/export/import RSA/ECDSA-keys with BouncyCastle, see the project called "BouncyCastleTests" in the same repository. I leave it to you to safely store and retrieve your own RSA/ECDSA private keys.

I've verified my library's results for HMAC-ShaXXX and RSA-XXX with JWT.io - it looks like they are OK. 
ECSD should be OK, too, but I didn't test it against anything.
I did not run extensive tests anyway, FYI.

Comment: Thanks for the great descriptive answer!!

Comment: It's code like this that makes me understand why people like using Node.js instead. And I'm a fanboy of .NET. :-\

Comment: This is all incredibly complicated, I am so strugling with this. Clearly non mature, imho. Reminds me of Windows 3 hello world app http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2014/12/The-Infamous-Windows-Hello-World-Program.html

Comment: Who knows how route request  from class CustomBearerEvents to certain controller, jwt token was successfully validated, in my case when I try to call my controller method from rest client, it calls method in general controller and I don't have any CurrentUser in HttpContext, but in CustomBearerEvents class I have CurrentUser

Answer (score 13):

The easiest option I have found so far is [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict). You say you want to avoid Entity Framework and OpenIddict - then you'll be doing a lot of coding yourself, effectively rewriting parts of OpenIddict and [ASOS](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server) (which OpenIddict uses) to do what they are doing anyway.

If you're ok using OpenIddict, this is practically all the configuration you will need, below. It's very simple.

If you don't want to use EF, that's possible with OpenIddict. I'm not sure how but that's the bit you'll have to figure out.

**ConfigureServices:**

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddOpenIddictCore<Application>(config => config.UseEntityFramework()); // this line is for OpenIddict
```

**Configure**

```
app.UseOpenIddictCore(builder =>
{
    // tell openiddict you're wanting to use jwt tokens
    builder.Options.UseJwtTokens();
    // NOTE: for dev consumption only! for live, this is not encouraged!
    builder.Options.AllowInsecureHttp = true;
    builder.Options.ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true;
});

// use jwt bearer authentication
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    // these urls must match the value sent in the payload posted from the client side during login
    options.Audience = "http://localhost:58292/";
    options.Authority = "http://localhost:58292/";
});
```

There are one or two other minor things, such as your DbContext needs to derive from `OpenIddictContext<ApplicationUser, Application, ApplicationRole, string>`.

You can see a full length explanation (including links to the github repo) on this blog post:
http://capesean.co.za/blog/asp-net-5-jwt-tokens/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll give this a try. As far as authentication goes my server will be completely stateless so I don't really understand what EF is being used for. I read somewhere that you can write your own identity store instead of using EF. Not really sure what that means but I'll look into it

Comment: EF is used for storing the logins. This assumes you have your own logins you're authenticating against.

Comment: Capesan link here: http://web.archive.org/web/20160320170610/http://capesean.co.za/blog/asp-net-5-jwt-tokens/

Answer (score 9):

If all you need is authentication against an external OAuth/OpenID provider (such as Google, GitHub, Facebook, Microsoft Account etc.), then you don't need any third party tools.

Authentication providers for the most commonly used OAuth and OpenID providers are already provided with ASP.NET Core in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.*` packages. Check out the samples provided on the GitHub repository of the "[Security](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/samples)" repository

If you need to create your own JWT tokens, then you need an OAuth/OpenID server. OpenIddict is an easy to setup authorization server. For this you need some form of database, as external providers will be used to authenticate the person, but you also need them to have an account on your authorization server.

If you need more customization and more control of the flow, you got to use ASOS or IdentityServer4 (currently only supported on ASP.NET Core when working against full .NET Framework or Mono. Core runtime isn't supported yet as far as I know.

There is also a Gitter Chatroom for OpenIddict at  https://gitter.im/openiddict/core and https://gitter.im/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server for ASOS.

Answer (score 2):

There is a full example for ASP.NET Core + JWT Auth + SQL Server + Swagger: https://github.com/wilsonwu/netcoreauth

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Can you please copy essential parts from there because link can become invalid?

Comment: I plan to update to .netcore 2.0, but currently the Azure Website has not good compatibility with .netcore 2.0, I will try and deploy later.

Comment: I think the github will not close before stackoverflow :).

Answer (score 1):

Securing **ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API** with **Standard JWT Bearer Token** based authentication

https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login

& apply the authorize filter as follows

```
 [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a package which

- Makes integrating JWT Bearer Token Security in your Asp Net Core 2.0+ app a breeze!
- Azure Active Directory auth integration.
- Facebook auth integration.
- Also, Swagger UI integration!

It is called **AspNetCore.Security.Jwt**

GitHub:

https://github.com/VeritasSoftware/AspNetCore.Security.Jwt

The package integrates JWT bearer token into your app as below:

### 1. Implement IAuthentication interface in your app

```
using AspNetCore.Security.Jwt;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace XXX.API
{
    public class Authenticator : IAuthentication
    {        
        public async Task<bool> IsValidUser(string id, string password)
        {
            //Put your id authenication here.
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

### 2. In your Startup.cs

```
using AspNetCore.Security.Jwt;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;
.
.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    .
    .
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "XXX API", Version = "v1" });
    });

    services.AddSecurity<Authenticator>(this.Configuration, true);
    services.AddMvc().AddSecurity();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    .
    .
    .
    // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), 
    // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "XXX API V1");
    });

    app.UseSecurity(true);

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

### 3. In your appsettings.json

Note:- You can put these settings in Secret Manager by using Manage User Secrets menu (right-click your Project).

```
 {
     "SecuritySettings": {
        "Secret": "a secret that needs to be at least 16 characters long",
        "Issuer": "your app",
        "Audience": "the client of your app",
        "IdType":  "Name",
        "TokenExpiryInHours" :  2
    },
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Then you will get endpoints automatically:

> /token
>
> /facebook

When you call these endpoints and are successfully authenticated, you will get back a JWT Bearer Token.

### In your Controller that you want to secure

You must mark the Controller or Action that you want to secure with Authorize attribute like:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    .
    .
    .

    namespace XXX.API.Controllers
    {
        using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

        [Authorize]
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        public class XXXController : Controller
        {
            .
            .
            .
        }
    }
```

In Swagger UI, you will automatically see these endpoints.

[image: Auth]