# ASP.NET 5 RC1 Identity Authentication method

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core

I can't find anywhere answer on question what is default authentication in `ASP.NET 5 RC1`, is it token based or cookie based. All i know is if i say `app.UseIdentity()` in my Startup.cs and i put `[Authorize]` attribute on my controllers, it is gonna work, but i can't figure out which method it uses. There are so many tutorials for token based authentication for `ASP.NET 4.6` but things are different, i can't figure out how to apply that stuff in new `ASP.NET 5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Identity 3 exclusively relies on cookie authentication (`app.UseIdentity()` is basically just a wrapper around `app.UseCookieAuthentication()`).

There are already a few SO posts covering token authentication. Here's one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35310717/542757

Answer (score 0):

Its cookie authentication. You can check it out here https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/BuilderExtensions.cs