# how to make async calls to run synchronously in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, membership-provider

I have this this code

```
ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password)
```

I want this code piece to run Synchronously, because my very next statement is depend upon this. Below call fails most of the time because user is null.

```
var roles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: How about to check ```if (user!=null){/* do your stuff*/}``` ?

Comment: Pretty sure this is nothing to do with being async, the `await` keyword should take care of pausing execution. Are you sure the call to get the ApplicationUser is succeeding? Sounds like it's returning null.

Comment: You don't need to do anything - the next line will run **ONLY** after `FindAsync` completes. if `roles` isn't what you expect, check for coding or data issues, not problems with async

Comment: Am I missing something? The `GetRolesAsync` will be executed after `FindAsync` is completed anyway. That's how `await` works.

Comment: How making it synchronously will help you ?

Comment: Make sure your `user` exists. When `Find` may return `null` when no user found.

Comment: The method will return `null` if there is no match. `await` has nothing to do with it. Either username or password is wrong

Comment: Why the upvotes to an obviously wrong and un-answerable question?

Comment: @Sachin: I think the confusion is that you want it to run *serially*, not *synchronously*. `await` is how you do asynchronous *serial* code, so it works just fine as-is.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with the code. `await` means that execution continues only *after* the asynchronous method that follows finishes. This means that in this snippet:

```
var user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password)
var roles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
```

the call to `GetRolesAsync` will be executed only *after* the previous line completes.

From the documentation of [UserManager.FindAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497605(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager%602.FindAsync%28System.String,System.String%29)

> Returns a user with the specified username and password or null if there is no match.

Either the username or password are wrong. Just return a message to the end user asking them to retry. If you make this call using stored credentials, check them again.

In any case, you need to check for an authentication failure before trying to use the `user` value, eg:

```
var user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password)
if (user == null)
{
    //Somehow report failure, decrement retry counters, etc
    retries--;
    return false;
}
else 
{
    var roles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ApplicationUser user = userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password).Result;
var roles = userManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id).Result;
```

But if the context user just is null, it won't help you if you do it synchronously - user will be just as NULL as it was before.

If you are trying to add a login to your application, it might help to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307143/simple-jwt-authentication-in-asp-net-core-1-0-web-api/39822153#39822153).
Also, you should probably use [policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies) instead of roles.

**Edit:**
OK, without deadlock-problem I was unaware of (thanks @hvd):

```
var user = Task.Run(() => userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password)).Result;
var roles = Task.Run(() => userManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id)).Result;
```

If the async method returns void

```
Task.Run( () => asyncMethod()).Wait();
```

Comment: There's no need for this. The original code has no problem

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: I know, but it's the answer to his question.

Comment: @StefanSteiger The problem is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The *real* problem is `user` being `null`, not the code running asynchronously. Your answer should fail for the real problem in exactly the same way as the OP's own code, plus additionally, you've introduced the possibility of deadlock depending on where this code is called and how `FindAsync` is implemented.

Comment: FindAsync returns null if the username and password don't match. Using `.Result` will still return null

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: I never said his problem would be solved by this - i just answered how to make it synchronous, which was his question ;)

Comment: This code deadlocks on my single CPU azure build agent

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why there could be problem - if you `await` properly, `user` should be properly fetched before `GetRolesAsync` call. Is this your whole code?

Mayby, `user` is `null` because it doesn't exist?

Besides, you can chain your calls instead of running it synchronously:

```
var roles = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password)
                             .ContinueWith(task => 
                                              userManager.GetRolesAsync(task.Result.Id))
                             .Unwrap();
```

Comment: Chaining won't change anything. The effect will be the same as `await`. If the result is null, the chained method will fail itself