# ASP .NET Core Identity default authentication vs JWT authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing ASP NET Core Web API and I am confused by choosing the authentication method. I used to apply default Asp Net Identity authentication, but recently I've known about JWT. So I've implemented Authentication almost as it done in this article: https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core.
But I can't understand the benefits of this JWT. With simple Asp Net Identity Authentication, I don't care about token storage etc. I only need to log in with signInManager and use authorized methods until logout. With JWT I need to think about the token store, expiration, and other difficulties. So, what're the benefits of this JWT? How can I store this JWT token after login? Furthermore, should I even use this JWT? In my case, I need simple authentication for simple WebApi which will be used by one or little bit more users. I've also heard about OpenIddict, Auth0, IdentityServer, so what's the difference between all of these authentication mechanisms?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is the way I understand this, split in to 3 logical parts.

1. Authentication Server - this will authenticate and issue the JWT token, when the API need's to validate the token it will send the token to this server to validate it.
2. Client - this is what serves your web pages, or you app perhaps. This is what will need to request and store the the JWT token. The client will need to pass the token to the api every time it requests data.
3. API - this is what serves the information and needs to validate the token with the Authentication Server.

> So, what're the benefits of this JWT?

JWT is issued to the client and stored on the client side. Having JWT allows multiple client's (App's or Websites) use the same authentication server which distributes JWT and states which API's the client's can use and how.

> How can I store this JWT token after login?

I only tried to store it in an Ionic 2 app which uses angular 2 which has a storage module. But i'm pretty sure numerous people have done this already and asked this question:

[Simple JWT authentication in ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307143/simple-jwt-authentication-in-asp-net-core-1-0-web-api)

[Token Based Authentication in ASP.NET Core (refreshed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546542/token-based-authentication-in-asp-net-core-refreshed/33217340#33217340)

**Update**
If your front end is made purely html/js/css and doesn't have a back end to accommodate it you would store your token in local storage, there a multiple npm packages that help you with this [like this one](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js). You want to look for Implicit flow.

Otherwise if you do have a back end that comes with your front end you want to store the token in a session/database your pick, there are 3rd party providers to do this like IdentityServer4. You want to use Hybrid flow

> Furthermore, should I even use this JWT? In my case, I need simple
>   authentication for simple WebApi which will be used by one or little
>   bit more users.

The reason for the whole separation of concerns is performance so you don't really need it since it's just one or a little more users. **Do it because it's a learning experience, JWT is not easy to setup from the beginning and will require you to do a lot of reading and you will fail and you will be frustrated but at the end you will know how to set it up and how it works**

> I've also heard about OpenIddict, Auth0, IdentityServer, so what's the difference between all of these authentication mechanisms?

So what you did in the Stormpath tutorial is NOT production ready. That is just a little demo, to help you understand what JWT is and how it works. The above mentioned are complete libraries that tackle all the heavy lifting and do not require you to built the whole thing from scratch. And the main difference between them is the scope that they cover.

I personally used IS4 and it had me crying no more than 2 times (It was simpler than I thought):
http://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/

https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/aspnet-core/00-intro

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, if I decide to use authentication for one Web Api, which make authenticated requests to another Web Api, the best solution will be something like Single Sign On? (IdentityServer4, Auth0)?

Comment: @AndrewK The client passes the token to an api, and that api validates the token with the Authentication Server, if you have multiple api's you just point them to the same Authentication Server, that way multiple api's/clients can use Single Sign On, since the token issued is from the single Authentication Server. Keep in mind that the Authentication Server is not an API. I used Identity Server 4 and it allows you to create an Authentication Server which can issue and validate tokens. Note: if you have 1 api calling another you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Anton I think that asp.net identity doesn't use sessions, it's just the users claims encrypted and put into a cookie, so we don't gain any performance, but by using tokens the api server has to make a call to the auth server to validate the token so as performance I think cookies is better.

Comment: @AntonToshik but how do you persist this token? like user comes back to your site after 2 days, without using cookies she will have to login again. So what's the benefit at all?

Comment: @lll The advantage is Single Sign On: 1 point of authentication. You know how you can log in to Instagram using your Facebook account and then never log in again. The type of application you are developing will require you to use a certain authentication flow, which will then have different ways of requesting new `access tokens` or `id tokens`. Ultimately the usefulness of this depends on your use case.

Comment: Doesn't .net identity have jwt option?

Answer (score 13):

Use tokens (JWT) if you have multiple applications or services (web, mobile, other services) connection to your API. Benefits: Stateless, Scalability, No cookie, no CORS problems (if you allow it).

If your API will be used by only one web application use the default ASP default authentication system. Its easier to set up.

Answer (score 4):

If you webapi and user interface are hosted in the same web application, token bases security does not buy you anything over the cookie based authentication provided by the built in authentication. That's because the authentication cookie gets sent back to the keep application on every HTTP request. When you make calls to a website other than the one you signed in on those cookies do not get sent. So JSON Web Tokens (JWT) provide a standard format for browser to send identity information to a website when a cookie isn't an option.

Answer (score 3):

If your Web Api is to be accessed by AJAX calls then JWT may be a desired choice, but not mandatory. judging by the description of your app,it seems to me that the default authentication system can serve you well.
Auth2 is the authentication mechanism that enable external login such as Facebook. It is part of the default authentication system, and you need not do much in order to employ it in your app.

OpenIddict sits on top of Auth2. It is part of the default authentication system, and you need not do much in order to employ it in your app. It is the authentication mechanism that enable external login such as Google+

IdentityServer may be used for large Wep Api that is accessed by Ajax calls. As for instance, you can use IdentityServer to authenticate users longing to a front end Angular app.

Once again, the default authentication system can serve you well.

Hope this helps...