# Decode/Read a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) Using Java or BouncyCastle

Tags: java, security, ssl, bouncycastle

I am generating a CSR (certificate signing request) using code without an issue with the appropriate information.  I need pointers to figure out how to read the CSR content using Java and/or BouncyCastle.

Any pointers or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Might be usefull : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230330/sign-csr-using-bouncy-castle

Answer (score 10):

Figured it out:

1. Convert the CSR PEM to a PKCS10CertificationRequest
2. Get the X500Name instance by accessing the getSubject() method from PKCS10CertificationRequest instance
3. Iterate over the RDN[] array and get the specific field you want using one of the ASN1ObjectIdentifier's (for example COUNTRY is 2.5.4.6)

Here is the code:

```
public class EncryptDecrypt {
    private Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EncryptDecrypt.class);
    private final String COUNTRY = "2.5.4.6";
    private final String STATE = "2.5.4.8";
    private final String LOCALE = "2.5.4.7";
    private final String ORGANIZATION = "2.5.4.10";
    private final String ORGANIZATION_UNIT = "2.5.4.11";
    private final String COMMON_NAME = "2.5.4.3";


    @Test
    public void testReadCertificateSigningRequest() {
        String csrPEM = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n" +
                "MIICwjCCAaoCAQAwfTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEDAOBgNVBAgTB0Zsb3JpZGExEzAR\n" +
                "BgNVBAcTCkJvY2EgUmF0b24xGzAZBgNVBAoTEkxvb25leSBUb29ucywgSW5jLjEU\n" +
                "MBIGA1UECxMLRGV2ZWxvcG1lbnQxFDASBgNVBAMTC2V4YW1wbGUuY29tMIIBIjAN\n" +
                "BgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAiJCj31d1Rp+aKz/GTkedaiS/VSCc\n" +
                "PRARYgXukobjgBHx46HjldAcfg/DoANn5lEQaFxaIZJLbZ/AdLUyw/hUbU0CjWXv\n" +
                "pN3Ep3o9XgRTPkIFoI22VOI/O2ZLjBq/E4DWyVmv+vG6BK0LRh7hykzPCw6KIRR9\n" +
                "NCmUMJMQX5d5P/r1lR5H399pnLcLsrHoWDwBSEDgkGWyxnvEB0+/bIz42T3qnlFt\n" +
                "7avarxlHG2p5DoRTf8GJ+6imY88ZeBW/Nk18aDINsAHWLv383JICIAsZ3VuMk8m/\n" +
                "Z/Z5b21zIuZECDJjZjvAAjr/shVLB+Pck5+HJy6tqj79MJOQu+jKIrK8VwIDAQAB\n" +
                "oAAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAGtuAAHG4OC9jSRjGWSqfMXTDMz9tgekDREA\n" +
                "SYv5QIrOXsMzwbgDw8LxRJZEskl4JJOnjwEvUXWUF1M6XmG2h358nOnrkOlsumHw\n" +
                "Tx5gGSr6S6aJO/HG46erctE8aWpnFZYMfuEkul4ApsIufL7Bxqs3NHZWcrWBlLIP\n" +
                "aVCKx1FPRMC36Tj3EslbuUB/iTRt90Nfq1IxHMIKiwCiSNJSqfRVLANhI8MUbOjB\n" +
                "CBly1wcH68WWNkyvHVvbcF/B9AfYG9AqWjZjygKpyf81VZWctXhDc8UtomqrblXN\n" +
                "mvz4RKpIhZQLuuxlBrdzJkPm2sOdtdZghebCRRVWdjsig4sylgQ=\n" +
                "-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----";

        PKCS10CertificationRequest csr = convertPemToPKCS10CertificationRequest(csrPEM);

        X500Name x500Name = csr.getSubject();
        System.out.println("x500Name is: " + x500Name + "\n");

        // country is 2.5.4.6
        System.out.println("COUNTRY: " + getX500Field(COUNTRY, x500Name));
        // state is 2.5.4.8
        System.out.println("STATE: " + getX500Field(STATE, x500Name));
        // locale is 2.5.4.7
        System.out.println("LOCALE: " + getX500Field(LOCALE, x500Name));


    }

    private String getX500Field(String asn1ObjectIdentifier, X500Name x500Name) {
        RDN[] rdnArray = x500Name.getRDNs(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier(asn1ObjectIdentifier));
        String retVal = null;
        for (RDN item : rdnArray) {
            retVal = item.getFirst().getValue().toString();
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    private PKCS10CertificationRequest convertPemToPKCS10CertificationRequest(String pem) {
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        PKCS10CertificationRequest csr = null;
        ByteArrayInputStream pemStream = null;
        try {
            pemStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pem.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            LOG.error("UnsupportedEncodingException, convertPemToPublicKey", ex);
        }

        Reader pemReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pemStream));
        PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(pemReader);

        try {
            Object parsedObj = pemParser.readObject();

            System.out.println("PemParser returned: " + parsedObj);

            if (parsedObj instanceof PKCS10CertificationRequest) {
                csr = (PKCS10CertificationRequest) parsedObj;

            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOG.error("IOException, convertPemToPublicKey", ex);
        }

        return csr;
    }

    private String toPEM(Object key) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PEMWriter pem = new PEMWriter(sw);
        try {
            pem.writeObject(key);
            pem.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.printf("IOException: %s%n", e);
        }
        return sw.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is worth noting that `ASN1ObjectIdentifier`s are stored in the `BCStyle` static class as `public static final ASN1ObjectIdentifier`s, so things like `COUNTRY` don't need to be recreated from zero. However, it is not an `enum`.

Comment: Nice, thanks for sharing. See my updated code for Kotlin/ Android below.

Answer (score 1):

I propose this "simple" solution to read a csr

You must add dependency with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.62</version>
</dependency>
```

Create new object CSRObject

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.RDN;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS10CertificationRequest;

import java.io.*;

public class CSRObject {
    private final X500Name x500Name;

    public CSRObject(final String csr) throws IOException {
        final Reader pemReader = new StringReader(csr);
        final PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(pemReader);
        x500Name = ((PKCS10CertificationRequest) pemParser.readObject()).getSubject();
    }


    public String get(final CSRObjectEnum field) {
        RDN[] rdnArray = x500Name.getRDNs(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier(field.code));
        String retVal = null;
        for (RDN item : rdnArray) {
            retVal = item.getFirst().getValue().toString();
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public enum CSRObjectEnum {
        COUNTRY("2.5.4.6"),
        STATE("2.5.4.8"),
        LOCALE("2.5.4.7"),
        ORGANIZATION("2.5.4.10"),
        ORGANIZATION_UNIT("2.5.4.11"),
        COMMON_NAME("2.5.4.3"),//
        ;
        private final String code;

        CSRObjectEnum(final String sCode) {
            code = sCode;
        }

    }
}
```

And you can test with this method :

```
@Test
public void test() throws IOException {
    final CSRObject csr = new CSRObject(TEST_CERTIF);
    for (final CSRObject.CSRObjectEnum field : CSRObject.CSRObjectEnum.values()){
        LOGGER.info("{}:{}", field.name(), csr.get(field));
    }
}
```

with TEST_CERTIF is String

```
private static final String TEST_CERTIF = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n" +
        "...\n" +
        "-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I built on [David's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497209/david) answer to verify CSR content for a unit test in Kotlin on Android. It assumes you have the CSR in string format to begin with. CSR was generated using SpongyCastle `JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder`.

```
class yourCsrTestClass {
    ...
    private lateinit var csrContent: PKCS10CertificationRequest
    ...
    @Test
    fun yourCsrTest() {
        //This creates a CSR with SpongyCastle which we will test
        val csr = yourCSRService.generateRequest()

        //Convert our CSR string in modified code from David
        convertCsrString(csr)

        //Get x500Name subject
        val x500Name = csrContent.subject

        //Assert test as true if content matches as intended
        //This can be applied to any CSR attribute
        assertTrue(getX500Field(BCStrictStyle.O.toString(), x500Name) == "Your intender organization name")
    }
    ...
    private fun convertCsrString(pemCsr: String) {
        val stream = ByteArrayInputStream(pemCsr.toByteArray())

        val pemReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(stream))
        var pemParser: PEMParser? = null
        try {
            pemParser = PEMParser(pemReader)
            val parsedObj = pemParser.readObject()
            println("PemParser returned: $parsedObj")
            if (parsedObj is PKCS10CertificationRequest) {
                csrContent = parsedObj
            }
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            Log.d("IOException, convertPemToPublicKey", ex.toString())
        } finally {
            if (pemParser != null) {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(pemParser)
            }
        }
    }
    ...
    private fun getX500Field(asn1ObjectIdentifier: String, x500Name: X500Name): String {
        val rdnArray = x500Name.getRDNs(ASN1ObjectIdentifier(asn1ObjectIdentifier))

        return rdnArray[0].first.value.toString()
    }
}
```