# Creating Self Signed Certificate and KeyStore from GUI

Tags: java, swing, ssl

We have an application locally hosted on which we create self signed certificate and keystore using java keytool command line utility in order to run the application over https.

We are now changing and wants to create keystore and self-signed certificate from a Graphical User interface. So is there any opensource tool available which can cater all the requirement or I have to develop this using Java Swings?

Please suggest what is the best option.

Comment: You can make a ".bat" file of the keytool commands which make a certificate and run that file from GUI .. using Java swing you can do this.

Comment: we are using linux as the operating system

Comment: well in that case you have to make shell script

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's nothing in the public API of the JRE to let you do this, but you can issue certificates using third-party libraries such as BouncyCastle. There is a snippet of code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23736305/372643) to give you an example (although don't forget to read the question and its answer if you want to avoid that particular problem). Of course, you can also look at the documentation for `X509v3CertificateBuilder` directly too.

It's not very difficult to use, but you may need to try multiple solutions first, to get to the point where you generate a certificate with the attributes and extensions you need.

It's worth keeping using `keytool` during development, to export and compare certificates. Using `openssl x509 -text ...` to check the content of the certificates you're generating is also useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20603012/230513), to execute the required [`keytool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) command. Use [`JPasswordField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html) to let the user enter the required `keystone` password. Consider using the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23588550/230513) with [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) and a self-signed certificate.