# RSA SHA256 signing in iOS and verification on Java

Tags: java, objective-c, swift3, rsa, digital-signature

1. I generated an RSA key pair with SecKeyGeneratePair. The key size in bits is 2048.

   ```
   NSDictionary *privateAttributes = @{(NSString *)kSecAttrIsPermanent: @YES, (NSString *)kSecAttrApplicationTag: PrivTag};
   NSDictionary *publicAttributes = @{(NSString *)kSecAttrIsPermanent: @YES, (NSString *)kSecAttrApplicationTag: PubTag};

   NSDictionary *pairAttributes = @{(NSString *)kSecAttrKeyType: (NSString *)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA, (NSString *)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: @2048, (NSString *)kSecPublicKeyAttrs: publicAttributes, (NSString *)kSecPrivateKeyAttrs: privateAttributes};

   SecKeyRef publicKeyRef;
   SecKeyRef privateKeyRef;
   OSStatus osStatus = SecKeyGeneratePair((CFDictionaryRef)pairAttributes, &publicKeyRef, &privateKeyRef);
   switch (osStatus) {
   case noErr:
       break;
   default:
       break;
   }
   ```
2. Create the X.509 format of the public key and send it to the server.
3. Create the SHA256 digest of the custom string with CC_SHA256.

   ```
   NSMutableData *hash = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:(NSUInteger)CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
   NSData *data = [stringToSign dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   CC_SHA256(data.bytes, (CC_LONG)data.length, hash.mutableBytes);
   ```
4. Sign the string with SecKeyRawSign method using kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA256.

   ```
   // Sign the hash with the private key
   size_t blockSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(privateKeyRef);

   NSUInteger hashDataLength = hash.length;
   const unsigned char *hashData = (const unsigned char *)hash.bytes;

   NSMutableData *result = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:blockSize];

   uint8_t *signedHashBytes = malloc(blockSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
   memset((void *) signedHashBytes, 0x0, blockSize);
   size_t encryptedDataLength = blockSize;

   OSStatus status = SecKeyRawSign(privateKeyRef, kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA256, hashData, hashDataLength, signedHashBytes, &encryptedDataLength);

   NSData *signedHash = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *) signedHashBytes length:(NSUInteger) encryptedDataLength];
   ```
5. Apply base64 on the signed data and send it to the server.
6. The java server cannot verify it with the public key.

I have the same above code in Swift.
As a debug step, I've exported my private key too and tried to follow the exact same steps in java. Until step 3 everything is the same. So, the iOS creates the same digest as the java app. The fourth step, the signing creates a different output than the java code.

Here's the java code:

```
final Signature instance = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
instance.initSign(privateKey);
instance.update(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(rawString.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

Comment: iOS and Java API for digital signature are different. `kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA256` uses a SHA256 digest, but in Java it is needed to use the raw data. `Signature.sign()` do the digest. Use `instance.update(rawString.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));`

Comment: may be the problem is step 2, exporting public key. Because iOS do not work with standard formats like PEM/DER. Take a look to my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735486/generate-a-csr-in-ios-library/37736209#37736209). It shows how to export the public key to DER. This key can be loaded by Java.

Comment: pedrofb yes, this is how I do it.

Comment: pedrofb your first comment is really solved the issue, but then this means, the iOS doesn't do the digest part. I have to verify it why does this happen.

Comment: I think it is just a difference in the API but the final result is the same . Java `Signature.sign` makes digest+pkcs1 and iOS `SecKeyRawSign` makes only the pcks1 signature using a provided digest.

Comment: Then, is your issue is completely solved?

Comment: Yes, the issues is solved and please put this as an answer, so I can accept it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digital signature API for iOS and Java is different but the result is the same.

iOS `SecKeyRawSign` with `kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA256` uses a SHA256 digest, but in Java `Signature.sign` requires the raw data and it makes digest+pkcs1. Use

```
instance.update(rawString.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```