# Bouncy castle create a certificate from openssl csr in java

Tags: java, openssl, bouncycastle

I generated a ca-certificate and a key with openssl.

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out $CANAME.key 4096
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key $CANAME.key -sha256 -days 1826 -out $CANAME.crt -subj '/CN=MyOrg Root CA/C=AT/ST=Vienna/L=Vienna/O=MyOrg'
```

Now I want to sign CSRs with those.
I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230330/sign-csr-using-bouncy-castle), but I can't use the accepted answer, because the class `PKCS10CertificationRequestHolder` seems not to exist anymore.

Based on the seconds answer I created this service.

```
public class SignService {

    private PrivateKey privateKey;
    private X509CertificateHolder certificateHolder;

    public SignService(
            String caPathKey,
            String caCert,
            String caKeyPassword
    ) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

        loadPrivateKey(caPathKey, caKeyPassword);

        PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(caCert));
        this.certificateHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) pemParser.readObject();

    }

    private void loadPrivateKey(String caPathKey, String caKeyPassword) throws IOException {
        PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(caPathKey));
        Object object = pemParser.readObject();
        JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");
        KeyPair kp;
        if (object instanceof PEMEncryptedKeyPair)
        {
            // Encrypted key - we will use provided password
            PEMEncryptedKeyPair ckp = (PEMEncryptedKeyPair) object;
            PEMDecryptorProvider decProv = new JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder().build(caKeyPassword.toCharArray());
            kp = converter.getKeyPair(ckp.decryptKeyPair(decProv));
        }
        else
        {
            // Unencrypted key - no password needed
            PEMKeyPair ukp = (PEMKeyPair) object;
            kp = converter.getKeyPair(ukp);
        }

        this.privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
    }

    public String signCRT(String crs_str) throws NoSuchProviderException, IOException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, OperatorCreationException, CMSException {

        PemReader p = new PemReader(new StringReader(crs_str));
        PemObject pemObject = p.readPemObject();
        PKCS10CertificationRequest csr = new PKCS10CertificationRequest(pemObject.getContent());

        AlgorithmIdentifier sigAlgId = new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find("SHA1withRSA");
        AlgorithmIdentifier digAlgId = new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find(sigAlgId);
        X500Name issuer = certificateHolder.getIssuer();
        BigInteger serial = new BigInteger(32, new SecureRandom());
        Date from = new Date();
        Date to = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (365 * 86400000L));

        X509v3CertificateBuilder certgen = new X509v3CertificateBuilder(issuer, serial, from, to, csr.getSubject(), csr.getSubjectPublicKeyInfo());
        certgen.addExtension(X509Extension.basicConstraints, false, new BasicConstraints(false));
        certgen.addExtension(X509Extension.subjectKeyIdentifier, false, new SubjectKeyIdentifier(csr.getSubjectPublicKeyInfo().getEncoded()));
        certgen.addExtension(X509Extension.authorityKeyIdentifier, false, new AuthorityKeyIdentifier(new GeneralNames(new GeneralName(this.certificateHolder.getSubject())), certificateHolder.getSerialNumber()));

        ContentSigner signer = new BcRSAContentSignerBuilder(sigAlgId, digAlgId).build(PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(this.privateKey.getEncoded()));
        X509CertificateHolder holder = certgen.build(signer);
        byte[] certencoded = holder.toASN1Structure().getEncoded();

        CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").build(this.privateKey);
        generator.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build()).build(signer, this.certificateHolder));
        generator.addCertificate(new X509CertificateHolder(certencoded));
        generator.addCertificate(new X509CertificateHolder(this.certificateHolder.getEncoded()));
        CMSTypedData content = new CMSProcessableByteArray(certencoded);
        CMSSignedData signeddata = generator.generate(content, true);

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        out.write("-----BEGIN PKCS #7 SIGNED DATA-----\n".getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
        byte[] cert_encoded = Base64.encode(signeddata.getEncoded());
        for (int i = 0; i < cert_encoded.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0 && i % 63 == 0) {
                out.write('\n');
            }
            out.write(cert_encoded[i]);
        }
        out.write("\n-----END PKCS #7 SIGNED DATA-----\n".getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
        out.close();
        return new String(out.toByteArray(), "ISO-8859-1");
    }
}
```

The method `signCrt` does not throw any exceptions and returns a string (I am not sure what).

I can't verify it or even show any information about the certificate.

This openssl command works with the same csr file, I want to do the same thing from java.

```
openssl x509 -req -in test.csr -CA $CANAME.crt -CAkey $CANAME.key -CAcreateserial -out openssl-signed.crt -days 730 -sha256
```

The certificate created with openssl is much smaller the of my java method (Don't know of this is a useful information).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you linked *tells you* what the code returns: "a valid PEM-encoded signedData object containing a signed Certificate chain (of the type that can be imported by keytool)". Actually it's not quite valid: (1) it doesn't put any linebreaks in the base64 as PEM officially requires -- which you fixed, although you did it at 63 not 64 as standard; (2) it uses `BEGIN/END PKCS #7 SIGNED DATA` whereas the [standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7468#section-8) is `BEGIN/END PKCS7` -- or in most cases `BEGIN/END CMS` because CMS is basically a superset of PKCS7. keytool ignores both of these flaws when reading a 'CA reply' (i.e. `-importcert` to an existing `privateKey` entry), but other software doesn't -- like BouncyCastle and OpenSSL. You already added line breaks; if you change the BEGIN/END labels to PKCS7 and put the result in a file you can read it with among other things

```
 openssl pkcs7 -in $file -print_certs # add -text for expanded details
```

However, calling this 'the type that can be imported by keytool' implies it is the only type which is false. keytool can read PKCS7 containing certs -- either PEM *or* DER -- but it can also read 'bare' X.509 certificates in either PEM or DER, and that is usually more convenient. To do that, replace everything from `CMSSignedDataGenerator` onward with something like for DER:

```
Files.write(Paths.get("outputfile"), certencoded)
```

or for PEM since you have Bouncy:

```
try( PemWriter w = new PemWriter(new FileWriter("outputfile")) ){
    w.writeObject(new PemObject("CERTIFICATE",certencoded));
}
```

or if you prefer to do it yourself:

```
try( Writer w = new FileWriter("outputfile") ){
    w.write("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n" 
        + Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(certencoded) 
            // MimeEncoder does linebreaks at 76 by default which 
            // is close enough and less work than doing it by hand
        + "\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\r\n");
}
```

Note: you may not need the `\r` -- PEM doesn't actually specify CRLF vs LF linebreaks -- but MimeEncoder uses them on the interior breaks and I like to be consistent.

This -- just the certificate -- is what your `openssl x509 -req -CA*` alternative produces, and that's why it's much smaller -- one cert is smaller than *three* certs *plus* some overhead.

Several more points:

- PEMParser can handle CSR just fine; you don't need the PemReader+PemObject detour
- using the entire SubjectPublicKeyInfo for the SubjectKeyIdentifier extension is wrong. OTOH nothing uses the SKI extension in a leaf cert anyway, so simplest to just delete this rather than fix it.
- in `certgen.build()` if you use `JcaContentSignerBuilder` instead of the `BcRSA` variant, you can pass `cakey` directly without going through `PrivateKeyFactory` and the signature scheme directly without going through two `AlgorithmIdentifierFinder`s -- as the `/*cms-sd*/generator.addSignerInfoGenerator` later in the code already does.
- speaking of the signature scheme, **don't use SHA1 for cert signatures** (or most others). It was already deprecated in 2013 when that answer was written, and in 2017 was publicly broken for collision (see https://shattered.io) after which many systems either reject it entirely or nag mercilessly for such use, and some related ones like git. In fact many authorities and checklisters now prohibit it for *any* use, even though some (like HMAC and PBKDF) aren't actually broken. Your `openssl x509 -req` alternative used SHA256 which is fine*.
- and lastly, issuing a cert is NOT 'sign[ing] {the|a} CSR'. You can just look at the cert contents and see it's not at all the same as the CSR or even the CSR body. You *create* (or *generate* as used in the Bouncy names) a cert and sign *the cert* -- in *response* to a CSR.

* at least for now; if and when quantum cryptanalysis works a *lot* of currently used schemes, including probably SHA256-RSA signature, will be in trouble and will have to be replaced by 'post-quantum' schemes which people are now working to develop. But if this happens, you'll see it on every news channel and site in existence.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. `PKCS10CertificationRequestHolder` is the class that does not seems to exists. I changed the header information and used the PemWriter, that works. I also updated the signature to sha256. And you are right to the crs isself is not signed I am going to change the title.